# windows cmd file shows error not copying

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When I execute the below copyWindows.cmd file from java it is opening new window and shows output as below.
Please help on this.

copyWindows.cmd:

```
@echo off
@echo Copying Test Content to Server
IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO testContentNotExist
IF NOT EXIST %2 GOTO radBatDirNotExist
copy /Y %1 %2
goto success
:testContentNotExist
@echo The test content %1 does not exist
exit 2

:radBatNotExist
@echo The rad Bat Directory %2 does not exist
exit 2

:success
@echo The test content %1 successfully copied to dir %2
```

Output:

```
Copying Test Content to Server
'testNotExist' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'radBatNotExist' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The test content  successfully copied to dir
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem is this line:

```
IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO testContentNotExist
```

Syntax is `IF NOT EXIST filename COMMAND`.

If `%1` is empty, this line is computed as:

```
IF NOT EXIST GOTO testContentNotExist
```

So it searches for a file named `GOTO`, which it doesn't find and tries to execute `testContentNotExist`- which is not a valid command.

Avoid that by using:

```
IF NOT EXIST "%~1" GOTO testContentNotExist
```

(same with the next line)

Comment: Hi thanks now it is not copying the content to remote windows system c drive is shared folder. whether anything I need to change the copy command